# $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x-a} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How would you approach a function like? $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x-a} ,\ a \neq 1$$

I tried plugging in the value 1, to get at the end $0/a$, hence $0$. But I am not sure whether or not it is correct. Could you give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $a\ne 1$, the function is continuous at $x=1$. So you can just plug in.

Comment: if you're not sure of your answer, you can plug in numbers in the calculator with distinct values of $a$, for example, try with $0.009$ and $1.001$ and see if it approaches $0$.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're all very helpful!

Comment: The problem statement does not says $a\neq 1.$ therefore you have to consider the case $a=1$ separately and find the limit. L'Hospitals rule will be applicable for the latter case.

Comment: @Bumblebee it does say that $a \neq 1$. At first, the post had a link to the expression,  I edited to write the expression in the post and forgot to mention that $a \neq 1$ my bad.

Comment: @youser202342 do you know about continuous functions?

Comment: Might be worth noting a good approximation for that is $\frac{x^2-1}{x-a}$.  Good approximation can be made more precise and would be very useful for a full on delta-epsilon proof of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments we only need to use continuity that is

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$$

as an laternative we can also proceed as follows

$$\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x-a}=\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x^2-1}\cdot \frac{x^2-1}{x-a} \to 1\cdot 0=0$$

since always by continuity

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{x-a}=0$$